# Porting an application from little-endian to big-endian architecture

Tags: c, network-programming, endianness

I have a TCP server developed on x86 architecture using C under Linux using berkley socker API. The server runs fine without any problems. But now for some reasons I have to run the server on MIPS architecture which has a `big-endian` architecture.

The server and the clients communicate through a set of predefined protocol. I will give an example of how a server sends a simple message to the clients:

```
struct echo_req req;

  req.header.version = OFP_VERSION;
  req.header.type = OFPT_ECHO_REQUEST;
  req.header.length = htons (sizeof req);
  req.header.xid = htonl(y);
  req.data = htonl (456);

char data[sizeof (req)];
data[0] = req.header.version;
data[1] = req.header.type;
memcpy (data + 2, &req.header.length, 2);
memcpy (data + 4, &req.header.xid, 4);
memcpy (data + 8, &req.data, 4);

  if ((send (sock_fd, &data, sizeof (data), 0) == -1))
    {
      printf ("Error in sending echo request message\n");
      exit (-1);
    }
printf("Echo Request sent!\n");
```

As you can see I use `htonl` and `htons` for any type longer than a byte to convert it to network byte order. After making up a packet I serialize and pack the data in `char` array and finally send it over to the netowrk.

Now before I run my server on Big-endian architecture I wanted to clear out a few things. In my perception as I `memcpy` the data and pack it, if I send it over the network it shouldn't cause any problems on the big-endian architecture as memcpy will perform a byte by byte copy of the data into the array and hence there shouldn't be any problem with the byte ordering when running on Big-endian. Yet I wanted to get the opinion of you people out there which I persume know a lot more than I do as I am still a beginner in network programming :). Please guide me in this whether I am on the right track or not. All help much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What you are doing is fine. Convert to network byte order before you put it on the wire. Reverse the process when you pull it off. There's nothing more to say.

Comment: I wanted to confirm the memcpy part. Is it Ok too ?

Comment: "I wanted to get the opinion of you people out there". Isn't that what http://codereview.stackexchange.com is for?

Comment: *Aside*: endianness is not the only problem. You should confirm that `sizeof (echo_req)`  is the same on both platforms.

Comment: Hi Rob, As I mentioned the server and clients communicate through a set of predefined protocol and echo_request is one of many structs defined in the protocol, so the size would always be the same at both ends. As far as the code review is concerned, well that would be too much to ask as the server total LOC is more than 10,000 lines :/ I will be very happy if someone could review it all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `memcpy` just copies bytes in order from a source to a destination.

Without seeing the rest of your code, it's impossible to say that you've used hton(l|s) everywhere you should. It's also possible that you've done something like copying a floating point number byte for byte, which doesn't necessarily work, independent of endianness issues.

I don't see any obvious problems in the code you've posted above though.

Comment: Yes I have tried to make sure that I use htonl/htons wherever required. Just had some reservations regarding memcpy so thought better confirm it :). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you use ntoh/ntos when receiving data as well?

BTW you should simply use the struct for sending data; re-assembling it into the character array does nothing but take CPU time and possibly bear errors.

Comment: Unless the struct is packed, you can't just send it as-is.  The copying is an effort to ensure that it is packed correctly.  That said, most compilers have a way to declare a structure as "packed", and using a packed struct would result in simpler code.

Comment: yes I have made sure the use of ntoh/ntos. I pack the struct because as tomlogic mentioned, sending structs as they are might cause problems because of different compilers different declaration of the structs, especially with architectures such as MIPS and ARM which do not allow unaligned memory access, the problem even gets worse. So better pack it in my opinion :)

Comment: @Abdullah - but then you send the packing along with the data! In the code you show us, you send `sizeof(echo_req)` bytes, which can vary according to platform.